# Generic way to create 2-dim arrays dynamically?

Tags: c, arrays

I am very new to use `C`, I wrote the code bellow to create a 2d `int` array, can anyone help to generic it to other types, like float, double ... ? or other function can be use directly?

```
int** alloc_arrays(int m,int n) {
    int **MN = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*m);
    if(MN == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<m;i++) {
        MN[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)* n);
        if(MN[i] == NULL){
            exit(1);
        }
        memset(MN[i],0, n);
    }  
    return MN;  
}

void free_arrays(int **arrays,int m){
    if(arrays==NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0;i< m; i++){
        if(arrays[i] ==NULL){
            exit(1);
        }
        free(arrays[i]);
    }    
    free(arrays);
}
```

Comment: All you need is to learn c++, which has template .that will solve your problem.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @n.m. We should have a [malloc_cast] macro for this comment...

Comment: @n.m. yes, no need to cast void*  in C. only need in C++.

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty, but it works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ALLOC_ARRAYS(ptr, M, N) do { \
    size_t m = (M), n = (N); \
    if ( NULL == ((ptr) = malloc(m * sizeof *(ptr))) ) exit(1); \
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) \
         if ( NULL == ((ptr)[i] = calloc(n, sizeof **(ptr))) ) exit(1); \
    } while (0)
```

Sample usage:

```
int main()
{
     double **ptr;
     ALLOC_ARRAYS(ptr, 5, 10);        
}
```

Note: `calloc` (or equivalently, `memset` to `0`) only generates well-defined values for integral types (or if you know your system is using IEEE754 for doubles). It might be better to explicitly initialize each element to an initializer that you pass to the macro; or have a different macro for initializing.

Comment: this code work well, but i don't know why added do...while here? this code still working when remove do while.

Comment: @lessisawesome it means you can use `ALLOC_ARRAYS` in any context where you can use a function call; e.g. `if ( foo ) ALLOC_ARRAYS(ptr, 5, 10); else other_func();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro like this:

```
#define MAKE_ARRAY(A, N, M) A = calloc(sizeof(**A) * N, M)
```

And you would use it like this:

```
int N = 4;
int M = 10;

int (*x)[M];
double (*y)[M];

MAKE_ARRAY(x, N, M);
MAKE_ARRAY(y, N, M);

/* ... */

free(y);
free(x);
```

Comment: `M` is redundant here since it is part of the type information, you could have the macro be `#define MAKE_ARRAY(A,N) ( (A) = calloc( N, sizeof *(A) ) )`. Incidentally this will work with non-array types too.

Comment: @Matt x,y are at block scope, what it's means?

Comment: This code illustrates how it is used in combination with the variable length array feature of C99. This only works in block scope (inside a function).

Comment: @jxh I'm not sure what you mean, `M` is redundant whether or not it is a VLA so it only serves to introduce a way to allocate the wrong amount of memory if you don't specify the matching value for `M`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Originally, I had the macro cast the return value of `calloc()` before assigning to the variable, and this was to verify the type of the array pointer `A`. Before publishing the post, I took out the cast.

Answer (score 0):

Your not far off. You can fix/improve your code by improving the allocation.

```
MN[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)* n);
```

should be:

```
MN[i] = malloc(sizeof(**MN) * n);  /* instead of malloc(sizeof(int)); */
```

using the variable itself, rather than `(int)` makes the allocation generic and reduces chance of mistake. `malloc` knows what you are allocating.

if you want to allocate and set the contents to `0` at the same time, use `calloc`. You could change the same line to:

```
MN[i] = calloc (n, sizeof(**MN));
```

**Note:** do not cast malloc or calloc. It only increases the chance of mistake.

Comment: Correct you are. Thanks for the catch.